# How to get Kubernetes Services IP address using GCP APIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to get the Kubernetes Service IP address (internal and external) using the Google Cloud Provider APIs.
How do I get the Kubernetes Services IP address using GCP APIs?

Thanks

Comment: isn't is something one would do with an api call to a cluster itself and not to a hosting platform underneath?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to know the IP service on your cluster, you have to run the following command on your cloud shell console:

~$ gcloud container clusters describe NAME-OF-THE-CLUSTER --zone ZONE-WHERE-THE-CLUSTER-WAS-CREATED

If you wanted to know the service network range, please use:

~$ gcloud container clusters describe NAME-OF-THE-CLUSTER --zone ZONE-WHERE-THE-CLUSTER-WAS-CREATED | grep service

And, if you wanted to know the endpoint IP Address, please use:

~$ gcloud container clusters describe NAME-OF-THE-CLUSTER --zone ZONE-WHERE-THE-CLUSTER-WAS-CREATED | grep endpoint.

About the API, please review [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters/list)

Comment: I don't believe any of the listed commands will reveal an internal and externall IP address of a service in Kubernetes, including the api call linked.

@Cleosson, please clarify if you are looking to get info similar to what you would get with kubectl get svc